# Errors converting lat and long values to sf coordinates

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, r-sf

I have a series of coordinates that I am trying to plot on simple maps. I have two columns containing latitude and longitude for each point, respectively. I am attempting to use the `st_as_sf` function to convert this data into sf points but I keep getting numerous errors, most recently

```
"Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I have tried changing the class of the data to numeric, double, integer, etc. and I continue to get this error.

Below is an example of my data

```
point      lat       long
1          38.254    -76.712
2          38.123    -76.710
3          38.438    -76.699
4          38.254    -76.712
5          38.232    -76.733

st_as_sf(coords=c(lat, long), crs=4326)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the arguments of `sf::st_as_sf()` function; in the first place must be your data object, most likely a data frame with columns named lat and long.

In the second place you specify `coords`, which should be a string vector of variable names, contained in your data object - so the names "lat" and "long" are expected enclosed in quotation marks (these are not R variables, but column names).

In the third place is expected a coordinate reference system to make sense of the coordinates provided in the second step; in case of WGS84 this will be 4326.

So consider this piece of code; it is formally correct, but places your points somewhere in Antarctica (should you flip the coordinates to long-lat the points would be placed in Washington, DC).

```
library(sf)

raw_pts <- data.frame(point = 1:5,
                      lat = c(38.254, 38.123, 38.438, 38.254, 38.232),
                      long = c(-76.712, -76.710, -76.699, -76.712, -76.733))

points <- st_as_sf(raw_pts, # first argument = data frame with coordinates
                   coords = c("lat", "long"), # name of columns, in quotation marks
                   crs = 4326) # coordinate reference system to make sense of the numbers
points

# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -76.733 ymin: 38.123 xmax: -76.699 ymax: 38.438
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   point               geometry
# 1     1 POINT (38.254 -76.712)
# 2     2  POINT (38.123 -76.71)
# 3     3 POINT (38.438 -76.699)
# 4     4 POINT (38.254 -76.712)
# 5     5 POINT (38.232 -76.733)
```